# Set css route for nested routes in Nuxt

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Nuxt site deployed on Firebase roughly following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYUWsjUxxUQ) for SSR configuration, it works great when navigating to the homepage and then going to any other route, however when going directly to, say, /products/1 the HTML is rendered server-side just fine, but it's trying to load the css from `/products/css/[hash].css`.

How can I set the route for these static files so that it always looks for them in '/', and not the subroute.

I've looked over the [Nuxt config documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt-config/) and don't think I see an option to change that.

My index.js on my functions folder is as follows, if that helps:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const config = {
    dev: false,
    buildDir: 'nuxt',
    build: {
        publicPath: '/'
    }
};

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

function handleRequest(req, res) {
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
    nuxt.renderRoute('/')
        .then(result => {
            res.send(result.html);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            res.send(e);
        });
}

app.get('*', handleRequest);

exports.ssrapp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Do you have an example on how you load the CSS?